# Как закрыть response body в okhttp?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-studio

При синхронном запросе в okhttp выводит в логах следующее сообщение:

```
W/OkHttpClient: A connection to http://........... was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
```

Прописал в коде закрытие, но результата никакого.
Не скажу, что сильно мешает работоспособности, но логи активно засоряет, и, думаю, что по-хорошему стоило бы убрать.
Или на это можно не обращать внимания?

```
Call call = client.newCall(request);
Response response = call.execute();
jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
if (response.isSuccessful())
{
    response.body().close();
    call.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы закрыть connect вообще, надо сделать так:

```
okHttpClient.connectionPool().evictAll();
```

***P/s*** [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614806/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B2-okhttp/614810#614810) задавал такой же вопрос, пришлось найти ответ :)