# Как закрыть коннект в okhttp?

Tags: java, okhttp

Собственно, имеется такой код:

```
private static String sendRequest(String url) throws IOException {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    String responseBody = response.body().string(); //идентично и с response.close()

    response.body().close();

    return responseBody;
}
```

Все дело в это строке:

```
response.body().close();
```

***Почему после использования этого метода, коннект не закрывается?***      Это критично, потому что после пары использований метода висит много потоков, которые хорошо грузят оперативку.
Собственно, аналогичные проблемы наблюдаются не только у меня:

- [Вопрос раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504181/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-response-body-%D0%B2-okhttp)
- [Вопрос два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071774/how-to-close-http-connection-with-okhttp)
- [Обсуждение с разработчиками](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2311) (не помогло. Говорят про то, что коннекшн не закрывается, если код не 200, но у меня все запросы проходят **идеально**)

***Заранее благодарен за ответы!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм. Интересно. Чтобы закрыть connect, надо сделать так:

```
okHttpClient.connectionPool().evictAll();
```